# Regex. Match value between conditional

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input that I need to extract a number from. The input could be in any of the following formats.

- Q29775.**3**-16-F4
- A12345-**03**-C1
- B09091-**03**
- C22221-**03**D5

In the above example, I need to extract the number 03 from the middle of the input. This number varies.  I've tried messing around with between regex's such as `(?<=\-).*?(?=-)` but I'm not getting anywhere.  Can anyone suggest a regex pattern that will extract the first occurrence of one or more digits after a dot or hyphen?

Comment: How much does it "vary"? What are the actual pattern requirements?

Comment: Suggesting anything is easy, but will it work for you? `Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=[.-])\d+")?.Value`?

Comment: When I say the number varies, I mean it can be 1, or 01, or 2, or 02 or 3 or 03 . . . Varies!. The number varies.  Your suggestion does not match a single example above. Not sure why you posted that.

Comment: To create a regex, requirements must be stated clearly, e.g. "one or more digits that occur immediately after a `.` or `-` chars". Is it the case here?

Comment: [My suggestion matches](https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/1) all of them. Just paste them one by one and see for yourself.

Comment: I think my ask is perfectly clear.  Lets not create noise.  Your suggestion matches nothing using https://regex101.com/

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/1, https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/2, https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/3 and https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/4. Always test regex solutions in code since regex testers are all tricky and havbe their own glitches and usage specifics.

Comment: `(?<=[.-])[0-9]+(?=[^0-9]|$)` - we want a number `[0-9]+` which is preceded by either `.` or `-` and followed by either by non-digit or end of the string

Comment: Dima, that `(?=[^0-9]|$)` is easier to write as `(?![0-9])` or just `(?!\d)`. However, there is no requirement in the question to make sure there is no digit after a number. It is basically the same as if there is no `(?!\d)` in the pattern. `[0-9]+` will consume all digits there are at that location anyway.

Comment: Fair cop, I apologise. It works one example at a time. That'll do me. Many thanks.  (?<=[.-])\d+

Comment: user2026382, you are not in a position to determine if your "ask is perfectly clear". The fundamental problem is that you are stating your requirements in terms of examples. For all we know you wish to match the first string of digits following a character that is neither a letter nor a digit. Examples are meant to illustrate; they are not a substitute for an unambiguous statement of requirements in words (such as the example given by @Wiktor above).

Comment: If you can say it : `a regex pattern that will extract the first occurrence of one or more digits after a dot or hyphen` why can't you do it ? It's something a beginner learns in 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```cs
var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<=[.-])\d+", RegexOptions.ECMAScript)?.Value;
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCLsoR/4).

The pattern means

- `(?<=[.-])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a `.` or `-` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

With `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, the `\d` shorthand character class only matches ASCII digits.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your comment; I have dropped my code - you were the first